# Ubuntu on my nexus 5

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have an issue after trying to install ubuntu to my nexus 5 and it is stuck in a loop how can I fix this problems can anyone help me

Comment: well it supports android devices and i have seen it work on a a nexus 5 so i gave it a go and now im stuck really stuck i here it can be fix if you tech savy thats what the google people told me i dont care about the warranty of my nexus i just want it fixed or restored to factory and i tried that it did not work either so no it is just looping in boot mode i tried recovery mode i tried many things

Comment: The _Nexus 5_ is not an officially supported device, so technically it is an off topic question for this site. You can try different USB cable, different USB ports, or a different computer to flash the device again. If you boot into the bootloader and run `ubuntu-device-flash --bootstrap --channel devel` it should flash it again. If you were running Android 5, you may have problems, as it is not a well tested configuration yet. Your best bet is to ask on IRC.